# How to analyze (very incomplete) round-robin data

Tags: r, logistic-regression, round-robin

I have a design in which I have pairs of individuals that compete against each other. Each pair thus has one winner.

- A vs B B wins
- B vs C C wins
- ...

I have also measured a continuous variable (X) of each individual and I expect that X predicts wins. Normally I would thus calculate a difference score for each pair and then predict the win
E.g.,

model <- glm(data$Winner ~ data$diff, family = "binomial" )
summary(model)

However, I do have a few individuals in the dataset who appear in multiple pairs (hence an "incomplete round-robin"):

- **A** vs B
- C vs D
- **A** vs E
- F vs G
- ...

I don't know how to account for these "overlapping" pairs in the analyses.

Thanks a lot for any input.

Answer (score 0):

You could also select a discrete choice model, where you model "A vs B" as a situation where A and B are possible choices and if A wins against B you model A as the chosen alternative. In R I know the package `mlogit` that can calculate such models.